# How to prove $\operatorname{div} \mathbf{A}=\operatorname{Div} \mathbf{A} \mathbf{F}^{-\mathrm{T}}$?

Tags: solid-state-physics, mathematical-physics, tensor-calculus, solid-mechanics

I recently focus on solid mechanics and I am reading *Nonlinear Solid Mechanics A Continuum Approach for Engineering by Gerhard A. Holzapfel*. However, I was confused by a mathematical formula eq(2.49), it is as follows,
\begin{equation}
\operatorname{div} \mathbf{A}=\operatorname{Div} \mathbf{A} \mathbf{F}^{-\mathrm{T}} \tag{2.49}
\end{equation}
where $\mathbf{A}$ is a smooth second-order tensor field, $\mathbf{F}^{-1}$ is the inverse of the deformation gradient. I tried to prove this formula but failed, my current progress is as follows,

---

\begin{equation}
\operatorname{div} \mathbf{A}= \frac{\partial A_{i j}}{\partial x_{j}} \mathbf{e}_{i} \\
\operatorname{Div} \mathbf{A} \mathbf{F}^{-\mathrm{T}} = \frac{\partial A_{i j}}{\partial X_{j}} \mathbf{e}_{i} \frac{\partial X_{k}}{\partial x_{l}} \mathbf{e}_{l} \otimes \mathbf{e}_{k}=\frac{\partial A_{i j}}{\partial X_{j}}\frac{\partial X_{k}}{\partial x_{l}}\delta_{il}\mathbf{e}_{k} = \frac{\partial A_{i j}}{\partial X_{j}}\frac{\partial X_{k}}{\partial x_{i}}\mathbf{e}_{k}
\end{equation}

---

I stopped here and can't reach that equation(2.49) in the book. Can someone help me?

Comment: What is the difference between a div and a Div?

Comment: And what is $F^{-T}$

Comment: $\operatorname{Div}$ is the divergence with respect to material coordinates while $\operatorname{div}$ is the divergence with respect to spatial coordinates. $F^{-T}$ is the transpose of $F^{-1}$.